# How can I check if text input matches a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, authentication, passwords

I have some javascript which is supposed to change the color of an h2 when the user inputs the right text (password). But the user can litterally enter anything and it will change the text color. Does anyone know how to fix this? Here is my code:

```
var code = ('user1'); 
var entry = $('.code').val();

$('.code').change(function(code_check) {
  if(code == entry) {
     $('.codeText').css('color', 'rgb(247,37,62)'); 
  } else if(code != entry) {
     $('.codeText').css('color', 'rgb(61, 216, 97)'); 
  }
});
```

Comment: What is your default color?

Comment: You're missing a selector may be a dot or a hash in 'user1'

Comment: 'user1' is supposed to be the text that the var entry; needs to match. And the default color is red.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the value of the input using `this` as the reference

```
$('.code').change(function(){
    $(this).css('color', function(){
       return $(this).val().trim() == code ? 'rgb(247,37,62)' : 'rgb(61, 216, 97)');
    }); 
});
```

Comment: @BhojendraNepal That's also an option, but there is `String.trim`, which is what I'm using

Comment: The variables are misleading, I realize, but the script is meant to change the color of a title that rests above the input field when the value is changed, not the text inside of it. Plus, your code is throwing an error: Unexpected token:

Comment: I am using codepen and am still getting the same error.

Comment: @user3697399 can you give the link?

Comment: @user3697399 your if condition needs an else clause which is missibing. But you don't need elseif here. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Bydzaz

Comment: @user3697399 you were doing something wrong in if condition Now i works http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XJaKbB